# 'Response' Object is not callable

Tags: python, asynchronous, python-requests, python-asyncio

I'm trying to execute multiple **POST** requests in parallel and am getting the error: `'Response' Object is not callable`

I can see that the POST requests are being made, and it appears the error occurs right when it's attempting the response status/content.

I'm not looking to import aiohttp

```py
import asyncio
import concurrent.futures
import requests
import logging

async def fetchAllPostHttp(params, auth):
    with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=10) as executor:
        logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
        logger.setLevel(config.LOG_LEVEL)

        loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
        futures = []
        results = []

        for param in params:
            futures.append(loop.run_in_executor(
                executor, 
                requests.post(url=param['url'], json=param['data'], auth=auth)
            ))

        for response in await asyncio.gather(*futures):
            logger.debug(
            f"Received {response.status_code}: {response.content}")
            results.append(response.content)

        return results

def doMultipleHttpPostRequests(params, auth):
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    return loop.run_until_complete(fetchAllPostHttp(params, auth))

# Array of urls to post
myUrls = [
    {
        "url": "https://example.com",
        "data": {}
    }
]

# Invoking the method to issue multiple http requests
doMultipleHttpPostRequests(
    myUrls,
    auth=("xxx", "xxx")
)
```

Comment: If my answer resolved your issue please mark it as correct and/or upvote it.

Comment: just got home and marked your answer correct, thanks again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line is wrong

```
futures.append(loop.run_in_executor(
                executor, 
                requests.post(url=param['url'], json=param['data'], auth=auth)
            ))
```

you should pass a function object like `requests.post` alongside parameters and your passing the result of the call to that function `requests.post(url=param['url'], json=param['data'], auth=auth)` So basically the interpreter is right your passing a `Response` object, which executor tries to call as a function. So to fix that use `functools.partial` to create a function with those arguments already set if you'd like to use keyword arguments like so:

```
func = functools.partial(requests.post,url=param['url'], json=param['data'], auth=auth)

futures.append(loop.run_in_executor(
                executor, 
                func))
```

Or pass them alongside in the correct order that `requets.post` expects like so:

```
 for param in params:
            futures.append(loop.run_in_executor(
                executor,
                requests.post,param['url'],None, param['data'],
            ))
```

Notice you cannot use key word arguments here, so be sure you are passing them in the right order, I had to omit `auth` in the second approach as it is not a positional argument

Comment: Note that the standard way to use keyword arguments with `run_in_executor` (and other similar functions) is through `functools.partial` or `lambda`. For example, `run_in_executor(functools.partial(requests.post, url=param['url'], ...))`

Comment: I would suggest completely omitting the variant that uses positional arguments and warns to "pass them in the right order" etc. - that way your answer can concentrate on the important part, the use of `run_in_executor`. But that's just a matter of taste.

Comment: @user4815162342 I agree that this is an inferior way to do it. However, for the sake of completeness I left it.